# how to override inner method function in outer

Tags: python

How to modify the code

```py
def mackfunc(a):
    def func(b):
        return a+b
    return func

f = mackfunc(1)
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
```

### The output is 2 and 3

```py
def mackfunc(a):
    def func(b):
        return a+b
    return func

f = mackfunc(1)
```

add sth here to this out

```py
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
```

I hope that the output here is 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `func` is a local variable, which cannot be interfered with from outside the function. You can either redefine `mackfunc` entirely, or wrap it.

```
# redefine
def mackfunc(a):
    def func(b):
        return a + b + 1
    return func

# wrap
orig_mackfunc = mackfunc
def mackfunc(a):
    orig_func = orig_mackfunc(a)
    def func(b):
        return orig_func(b) + 1
    return func
```

Comment: Can you modify the value of "a" in mackfunc outside the function? How to achieve this

Comment: You can modify the value of `a` if it is mutable. You cannot reassign `a` such that that change is reflected in the function. E.g. if `a` was an object that allows a mutable property, or a list, or a dict...  but not if it is integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function inside you inner function and then redefine it later

```
def custom(arg):
    return arg

def mackfunc(arg):
    def func(b):
        return custom(arg)+b
    return func


f = mackfunc(1)
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print()
def newcustom(arg):
    return arg + 1
custom = newcustom

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
```

OUTPUT

```
2
3

3
4
```

Hope this helps. :)